# Fingering/notes in this version of Elite Syncopations

Tags: sheet-music

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but does anyone know the notes/fingering for the trill in this video for Scott Joplin's Elite Syncopations. I am referring to 0:44 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE7x05LJj4w), right after the two C's. This trill is not in the sheet music that I could find. Any help or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't hear a trill in 0:44. There is a group of 5 quick ascending notes near 0:46. Is that what you are referring to? He's simply using fingers 1-2-3-4-5 to play A-Bb-C-D-E.